# Need to show oldest 3 items in one webpart and the remaining items in another webpart

Tags: web-part, filter

I have a scenario where I want to divide a list's items into 2 webpart views - one that shows only the x oldest items (people that should be seen next) and another list on the same page showing the remaining items.  This is like a "you are next" application that will display the people waiting and queue some to the top that were here first and are "ready" to be seen.
How do I accomplish this?  Not sure how to create the criteria that will update each time something in the list changes / is removed - and exclude those designated as the top 3 without replicating them.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate web parts. For the first, Edit Web Part > Edit the Current View >

1. Sort by Created By / filter by some sort of open value
2. Item Limit = 3

For the second one, there is no way (without doing some custom code) to show just the remaining records. You'll have to show the whole stack in the other one, sorted as you'd like.

Comment: That was what I was doing, but noted that I could have duplication in my other list since there is nothing that I have that triggers or sets a  column value to know that a person is on (or not on) the top of the list..  Other ideas?

Comment: Personally, I would suggest having a field that is essentially some sort of column with possible values of 'Open', 'In process', 'Closed'. If you're using InfoPath you can do it all behind the scenes. If you're not, you can just default to open and have whoever addresses the issue close it. Then look at the list items that are open and order by create date. 

It's never a fun thing to suggest extra columns, but you have to have some sort of status for these sort of things.

Comment: I am already using Infopath and a status field. I need to somehow show the remaining items without duplicating the top 3.  Is there a way to use a query web part that shows excluded items from the top webpart?
Can I use the date and time from the "newest created date" of the top 3 items and filter the bottom webpart based on entries that were created after that (so the oldest 3 are at the top webpart, and the others are in the bottom webpart?
I could also do something in Designer if that expands my options.
Thanks again for your feedback..

Comment: While you can do the top 3 easily enough w/ the above method, trying to 'split' into top 3 and non-top 3 is not part of the out of the box tool set. I would recommend using a REST service call and populate the data into two divs that way. The JavaScript for that would live in a script editor web part on the desired page.